# Angular - AsyncPipe with Observable map operator

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5

I'm trying to implement a small translation tool with Angular 5. The idea is to call a method from the template, which will translate the string from a dynamically generated list of translations.

In the code below, although the map operator is being called, the string is not showing up.

```
// NOT WORKING

@Component({
  selector: 'app-translate',
  template: '<h1>{{translate("Takeaway") | async}}</h1>'
})
export class TranslateComponent {
  private translateChange = new Subject<any>();
  private translateChange$;

  constructor() {
    this.translateChange$ = this.translateChange.asObservable();

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.translateChange.next({
        'Takeaway': 'To go'
      });
    }, 1000);
  }

  translate(str: string) {
    return this.translateChange$.map((nameList) => {
      return nameList.str || str;
    });
  }
}
```

---

Interestingly, if I remove the map operator and pass the string directly to the Subject, like below, then the string is getting displayed.

```
// WORKING

@Component({
  selector: 'app-translate',
  template: '<h1>{{translate("Takeaway") | async}}</h1>'
})
export class TranslateComponent {
  private translateChange = new Subject<any>();
  private translateChange$;

  constructor() {
    this.translateChange$ = this.translateChange.asObservable();

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.translateChange.next('To go');
    }, 1000);
  }

  translate(str: string) {
    return this.translateChange$;
  }
}
```

---

I would like to know why the `.map` operator does not play well with the `async` pipe and if there's a better approach to achieve the above.

Thanks!

Comment: This will not work: ```nameList.str || str```. You have to use ```nameList[str] || str```, otherwise it always tries to find a value with the key str, and not with the key you provided.

Comment: @tomvangreen Good spot! But still in this case it should return the passed string, because of the “|| str” that I have in place.

Answer (score 0):

So I see multiple things that seem a bit off in your example.

**Reuse existing libraries**

I don't see why you are trying to reinvent the wheel here. There are multiple translation libraries that already can be used with angular. I would suggest having a look at [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) and see if it serves your need.

But in case you still want to build your own, there are some other things.

**Subject**

My bests guess is that this is responsible for your problem. The async pipe is impure and hence needs to be reevaluated on each change detection cycle. It will not show anything before you first emit something with the subject. And after you emitted a value, it takes only one additional cycle to again leave the subscription hanging.

Try using a BehaviorSubject instead. A subject will only emit once, when a new value is set. A BehaviorSubject will always emit the last value that was set and you need to provide an initial value. Now let's say you have a block in your template that is hidden by an *ngIf. After 1000 ms (what you do in your constructor) the subject will emit a value. If you show a part in an *ngIf block after this has happened, it will never receive a value.

With a BehaviorSubject, the last emitted value will be used, so you should be fine in that case.

**Providing the functionality via a method in your component**

I think it is not a good idea to provide the translation by a method in your component. If you want to use the translation in any other component, you need to create a translate method. I would rather go for a custom pipe.

[ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) does this nicely like this:

```
{{ 'translationKey' | translate }}
```

And you can use it in every component.

I would probably create a translate service, which is responsible for keeping track of the active translations (basically, translate service holds the `translations$` observable) and a pipe which has the service as a depdendency and does the actual mappingn from translation dictionary to the translated value. If you decide to go this route, make sure that the pipe is marked as impure.

**Distinct until changed**

I would probably add a `distsinctUntilChanged()` operator after your map operator. You only want to emit values if they have changed. You might change the object containing your translations, but having some values stay the same. For that case you don't need to emit again.